# Java connect to a remote MS SQL server database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to the database on the remote MS SQL server, using the provided `connection string`. The connection string is as follows:

```
data source=qsss.gar.de\SQL2012,3000;initial catalog=City;persist security info=True;user id=usr;password=usr##2009;
```

I understand I should have the suitable **drivers**, so I have downloaded the SQL Server drivers from [microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21599](http://microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21599)
, and added them to the **build path** of my project. Those are `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar`.

I am just using this test code to see if the connection is established.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "qsss.gar.de\SQL2012,3000;initial catalog=City;persist security info=True;user id=usr;password=usr##2009;");
    
    
    System.out.println("Connected!");
}
```

Doing so, I get an error: ***Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0***.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add both jars to your classpath since they both contain the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`-class and in your situation the program loads the one from `sqljdbc.jar`. Remove `sqljdbc.jar` from your classpath and only add `sqljdbc4.jar` so your program will always load the correct driver-version.